# How to create a query which has dynamicly changed dataset in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create a query which is linking the data from multiple datasets, new table is created every month. I would like to create a variable which i could use to change table when new tables in datasets apperas,  with no need to change each name of the table.
I was trying to use "set" and "declare" function but it seems that these variables do not work in dateset names in BQ. Do You know what should i do?

DECLARE reporting_time string;
SET reporting_time = "202005";

SELECT layout_instability.cumulative_layout_shift.histogram.bin
FROM
`chrome-ux-report.country_pl.reporting_time`
where origin like '%sanofi.pl' or origin like '%zentiva.pl' or origin like '%zakrzepica.pl'
union all
SELECT layout_instability.cumulative_layout_shift.histogram.bin
FROM
`chrome-ux-report.country_de.reporting_time`
where origin like '%sanofi.de'

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant can You share an example? my structure of data set is : chrome-ux-report.country_code.year_moth like chrome-ux-repor.country_pl.202005. I am using dataset with different country code and i want to be able to swith beetwen year_month in one place, so for example change once from 202005 to 202006 and all dataset names are updated

Answer (score 0):

you can use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate)

First build query string and then pass it to above function